# print list of symbols in clojure

Tags: clojure, lisp

I was trying to print out a list of symbols and I was wondering if I
could remove the quotes.

```
(def process-print-list
  (fn [a-list]
  (cond (empty? a-list) 'false
  (list? a-list) (let [a a-list] (println (first a)) (process-print-
list (rest a) ))
  :else (process-print-list (rest a-list) ))))
```

the list is ('x 'y 'z))

with the following output:

```
(quote x)
(quote y)
(quote z)
```

I am Just trying to get it to print out:

```
x
y
z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `name` fn to get symbol name.

```
(def my-list (list 'x 'y 'z))

(defn process-list
  [a-list]
  (map #(name %) a-list))

(process-list my-list)
;=> ("x" "y" "z")
```

Or with printing

```
 (defn process-print-list
    [a-list]
    (doall (map #(println (name %)) a-list)) 
     nil)

  (process-print-list my-list)
  ;x
  ;y
  ;z
  ;=>nil
```

Or combine those to get return type you want...

Answer (score 7):

`('x 'y 'z)` is a syntactic abbreviation for `((quote x) (quote y) (quote z))`.  If you actually want a list of symbols (i.e. `(x y z)`), you're probably quoting too much somewhere.

```
'(x y z)          ;=> (x y z)
'('x 'y 'z)       ;=> ((quote x) (quote y) (quote z))
(list 'x 'y 'z)   ;=> (x y z)
```

Generally, do not construct lists using quotation unless you know what you're doing.  Use the `list` constructor instead.

On another note, I'd choose iteration over recursion here.  This works fine:

```
(doseq [sym some-list]
  (println sym))
```